# Play three mono audio files in three speaker

Tags: sound, sound-libraries, surround-sound

As a part of a psychology test, I have three mono audio files and I want to play them through three separate speakers simultaneously.

To aim this goal I bought an USB 5.1 surround sound card (Blaster OMNI Surround 5.1 from Creative).

I wand to have *file1* in left speaker, *file2* in right speaker and *file3* in rear speaker for example.

Is that possible?

I downloaded some sound editor softwares but I couldn't make them work as I want. Actually it is OK for the *file1* and *file2*. but for *file3* I can't hear anything. Moreover, a low volume version audio of *file1* and *file2* are play in rear speakers.

Can anybody help me how to handle this?

If I want to do it using programming, is there any library to control channels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I found the solution in another software named "[Sound Forge Pro](http://www.sonycreativesoftware.com/soundforgepro) v10".

Steps:

1. File > New >
2. Select "Surround 5.1" or "Surround 7.1".

[image]

In that page you will see 6 or 8 rows. Drag&Drop your files in these rows.
After that you can change the default channel assigned to row by clicking on the numbers at the top of right-side.

<s>Finally save the result as a file! :)</s>

**Update: When you save it as a single file and play that file with a player, Windows or Player add some noise of channels on each other automatically. So it you want the channels to be separate as precise as possible, play the final audio in the SoundForge environment itself, and don't play it with another player as a file.**
That's it.